# Merging masked image collections in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification

I am trying to merge two masked grassland classes extracted from the 2019 Copernicus global landcover 100m data product. I called grass1 and grass2  as separate variables and then used the `var grassland = grass1.addBands(grass2);` .The script seems to run but on adding the grassland layer for visualization, the grassland pixels are not showing on the map.

How should I go about merging these two image collections?

The link to the whole code; https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fwawerujohn%2FProject__Work%3ASamburu_Ruuning_Code%20(copy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addBands` takes the bands of two images and produces an image with *all* of those bands, *separately.*

To combine the pixels of two similar images, you need to specify *how* to combine them. For an "one atop the other" result — unmasked wherever either is unmasked, preferring the second image — use `grass1.blend(grass2)`. For other results, you can use the various arithmetic operators available for combining images.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. The solution works perfectly and I was able to apply it in combining pixels for other similar landcover images.

Comment: I have a follow-up question that I would appreciate if you could get some time to look at. Kindly have a look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/402581/181433?sem=2)