# Computing NDVI pixel based timeseries for specific landcover classes in Google Earth Engine for a specific time period

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, time-series

I am trying to optimize my Google Earth Engine to perform a pixel-based NDVI time-series analysis for my four landcover classes (grassland, forest, crops and shrubs). I masked these landcover classes from the Copernicus Global 100m land cover product and using them as my input dataset. I also had to subset a new Image collection that has the images that are used for charting the time series to avoid getting multiple ndvi values per single date per specific landcover as am working at the pixel level.

The script is running but only giving the same linear time series chart for each of the masked landcover classes at a specific time period(say 2019-2020). This should not be the case. What could I be doing wrong?

Ps: I am working with  Sentinel 2 Level 1C product. Currently, for me to be able to chart my scale is at 10,000 because of the high number of pixels am working with.

Here is the link to the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fwawerujohn%2FProject__Work%3ASamburu_Ruuning_Code%20(copy)

Here is the code:

```
//Load and extract the 2019 Copernicus global landcover 100m data product
var landcover = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")
.select('discrete_classification');

// Clip the image to the polygon geometry
var landcover_roi = landcover.clip(geometry);
    
// Add a map layer of the landcover clipped to the polygon.
Map.addLayer(landcover_roi, {}, "Samburu landcover");

// Show Samburu aoi with a blue outline
var outline = ee.Image().byte().paint({
  featureCollection: geometry, 
  color: 1,
  width: 2
});

//Add and center the outline
Map.addLayer(outline, {palette: ['blue']}, 'AOI')
Map.setCenter(37, 0.5, 9);

// Select the classes you are interested in analyzing
//Value 20 = Shrubs
//var shrubland = landcover_roi.eq(20).selfMask()

//Map.addLayer(shrubland, {}, "shrubland");

//Extract cropland masked cover and add to the map
// Value 40 = Cultivated and managed vegetation / agriculture
//var cropland = landcover_roi.eq(40).selfMask();

//Map.addLayer(cropland, {}, "cropland");

//Extract grassland masked cover, merge and add to the map
//Value 30 = Herbaceous vegetation
//Value 60 = Bare / sparse vegetation
//var grass1 = landcover_roi.eq(30).selfMask();
//var grass2 = landcover_roi.eq(60).selfMask();

//var grassland = grass1.blend(grass2);

//Map.addLayer(grassland, {}, "grassland");

// //Extract forest masked cover, merge and add to the map
// Value 112 = Closed forest, evergreen broad leaf
// Value 114 = Closed forest, deciduous broad leaf
// Value 116 = Closed forest, not matching any of the other definitions
// Value 124 = Open forest, deciduous broad leaf
// Value 126 = Open forest, not matching any of the other definitions

var for1 = landcover_roi.eq(112).selfMask();
var for2 = landcover_roi.eq(114).selfMask();
var for3 = landcover_roi.eq(116).selfMask();
var for4 = landcover_roi.eq(124).selfMask();
var for5 = landcover_roi.eq(126).selfMask();

var forest = for1.blend(for2).blend(for3).blend(for4).blend(for5);

Map.addLayer(forest, {}, "forest");


//Add Sentinel 2 Level-1C data product
//Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
//param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
//@return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
        .select('B.*')
        .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
}

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2017-10-01', '2018-05-31')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

print(collection);

//Step 1
// Create a function to extract the date of acquisition of the  images
var consult = function(image){
  var resul = ee.Dictionary({
    date: ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('y-M-d')
  });
  return ee.Feature(null, resul);
};

// Map this function to the filtered collection
var dates = collection.map(consult);
// Aggregate the FeatureCollection over the 'date' property
dates = dates.aggregate_array('date');
// Get distinct values of dates
dates = dates.distinct();


//Step 2
// Create function to filter images by the dates stored in the previous dates object
var reduceImgs = function(date){
  // Create end date as 1 day after the date passed to the function
  var date2 = ee.Date(ee.String(date)).advance(1,'day');
  // Filter collection according to date and date2
  var dayCollection = collection.filterDate(ee.Date(date), date2);
  // Calculate mean of the filtered collection
  var resul = dayCollection.mean();
  // Return the mean image and set the system start property = date
  return ee.Image(resul).set('system:time_start', ee.Date(date));
};


// Map the previous function over the dates object
var imgColNew = dates.map(reduceImgs);
// Create a new image collection from the previous list of images
imgColNew = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(imgColNew);

// Function to calculate and add an NDVI band to the the imgColNew
var addNDVI = function(image) { 
  return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('ndvi'));
};

// Map the function over the cloud filtered collection to add NDVI as a band
var imgColNewNDVI = imgColNew.map(addNDVI);

//Print the number of images in the new image collection that are filtered for analysis
print(imgColNewNDVI);
  

// Create palettes for display of NDVI
var visParams = {
  min: -0.1,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
    'FFBB22', 'FFFF4C', '648C00', 
    ],
};

// Make chart selecting the 'ndvi' band, indicate the desired reducer to apply over the complete masked landcover and the desired scale 
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
    imageCollection: imgColNewNDVI.select('ndvi'),
    region: forest.geometry(),
    reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
    scale: 10000
    }).setOptions({
      interpolateNulls: true,
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      title: 'grassland pixel based Ndvi timeseries Oct 2017 - May 2018',
      vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Date', format: 'YYYY-MMM', gridlines: {count: 12}}
    });
    
//Add the time series chart    
print(chart);

//Center the map to our study area 
Map.setCenter(37, 1, 8);
```